# Need to put JS modules in correct order

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I got a task to render a word using pure JavaScript and modules, but always got mistakes like params of `renderDOM` function is `undefined` and so on. I'm able to choose the order of scripts, use IIFE
here is html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root"></div>

    <script src="invert.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        window.render.renderDOM('.root', reverse('sseccus'));
    </script>
    <script src="dom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and 3 files with functions:

**dom.js**

```js
const TAG = 'div';

function createElement(tag = TAG, content) {
    const element = document.createElement(tag);
    element.textContent = content;
    return element;
}
```

**render.js**

```
const TAG = 'p';

function renderDOM(selector, content) {
    const root = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

    const element = createElement(TAG, content); // createElement из файла dom.js
    root.appendChild(element);
}
```

**reverse.js**

```
(function () {
    function reverse(str) {
        return str.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
})();
```

I've tried to add `type='module'`, added export or export default to the functions. As a result there must be "success" rendered.

Comment: What error do you have ? And also, you don't define `window.render` anywhere, or doing `var render = ...`, so `window.render` is always undefined no matter what. If what you want is to call your `renderDOM` function, then that function is available with `window.renderDOM ()` or simply `renderDOM()`

Comment: my mistake is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'renderDOM')

Comment: Yes that error is expected, you didnt define a render object anywhere

Comment: i modified my render.js but got the same error

Comment: ```window.render = (function () {
    const TAG = 'p';

 function renderDOM(selector, content) {
        const root = document.querySelector(selector);

        if (!root) {
            return;
        }

        const element = window.dom.createElement(TAG, content);
        root.appendChild(element);
    }

    return {renderDOM};
})();```

Comment: That also cannot work, you need something like `window.render = { renderDOM: () => {} }` but i'm not sure if it actually make sense, perhaps it's better to simply call `window.renderDOM()`

Answer (score 1):

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="root"></div>

    <script src="invert.js"></script>
    <script src="dom.js"></script>
    <script src="render.js"></script>
    <script src="reverse.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.render.renderDOM('.root', reverse('sseccus'));
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

render.js

```
  const TAG = 'p';

  function renderDOM(selector, content) {
    const root = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

    const element = createElement(TAG, content);
    root.appendChild(element);
  }

window.render = {renderDOM};
```

dom.js

```
const createElement = (() => {
  const TAG = 'div';

  return function createElement(tag = TAG, content) {
    const element = document.createElement(tag);
    element.textContent = content;
    return element;
}
})();
```